# How is a hyperplane defined by a single vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

This is technically about a homework problem, but I'm only asking for clarification on the statements made, not about solutions. Keep in mind I've had little practical experience with linear algebra.

I'm given a statement about the distance from a point to a hyperplane as well as an image to illustrate it:

[image: illustration of the distance from a point to a hyperplane]

> In binary classification, the distance $d$ of a point $\mathbf{x}$ to a hyperplane $\mathbf{w}$ is computed by the length of the projection of $\mathbf{x}$ onto $\mathbf{w}$, minus the distance $r$ to the origin:
>   $$
> d =  \mathbf{x} \cdot \frac{\mathbf{w}}{\| \mathbf{w} \| }  - r
> $$

I'm fine with the equation, but I'm not sure how a single vector **w** is used to uniquely define a hyperplane.

I was assuming **w** is interpreted two ways: 1) as pointing from the origin to a point on the plane, and 2) as a normal vector for that plane. However, if that were true, shouldn't **w** should be exactly as long as $r$? In the image it's definitely not.

The text goes on to state that the length of **w** doesn't matter, but if **w** were used to define the location of the hyperplane it definitely would.

In conclusion, *what's wrong with my assumption of how one vector defines a hyperplane, and how am I supposed to interpret it instead?*

Comment: You are right. It seems that the given statements are imprecise. They should choose a convention and then stick to it.

Answer (score 1):

$w$ is the normal direction of the hyperplane.

The length of $w$ doesn't matter because in the formula, we are going to normalize it anyway, that is $\frac{w}{\|w\|}$.

A hyperplane is defined in the form of $w^Tx+d=0$ and the distance can be calculated by $r = \frac{|d|}{\|w\|}$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm still confused. If $w$ only defines the normal direction of the hyperplane, then what defines its position? It seems to me that to calculate a distance, you need to know where the hyperplane is located in space.

Comment: I edited a formula to compute the distance to the origin.